# Make entityfieldquery a synonym of entity-field-queries

Tags: support, synonym-request

It seems that [entity-field-queries](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-field-queries) has more questions and information than [entityfieldquery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entityfieldquery).

Comment: I think the opposite would be best.

Comment: There are 85 vs 19, seems people is finding the first easier for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the tag is for the `EntityFieldQuery` class, I kept [entityfieldquery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entityfieldquery) and renamed it [entity-field-query](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-field-query) to make it clearer. I am now going to put in the tag wiki what was present in the the old wiki tag.

I didn't set any tag synonym, since that is reserved to those cases where editing a question to use the correct tag is not possible (i.e. the wrong tag is added to more questions than the ones from which is removed).